# Contribution Limit Changes as a result of McCutcheon vs FEC

Tags: united-states, law, campaign-finance

I'm interested in knowing how the contribution limits in the United States changed (so before and after) due to McCutcheon vs FEC for:

1. Contribution limits to a single candidate
2. Total contribution limits across all candidates.
3. Limits for donations to PACs
4. Limits for donations to State/District Party Committees
5. Limits for donations National Party Committees

The reason why I'm asking this is because the numbers I can find from a variety of sources all seem to be somewhat inconsistent, both with respect to each other, and also internally. Thus, I'm having difficulty separating which are the inaccurate ones from the correct ones. The sources that I have looked at so far include:

- http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/special/politics/overall-contribution-limits/
- http://www.fec.gov/pages/brochures/contrib.shtml#Chart
- http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/04/02/us-usa-court-election-idUSBREA3116V20140402
- http://edition.cnn.com/2014/04/02/politics/scotus-political-donor-limits/
- http://www.publicintegrity.org/2014/04/22/14611/mccutcheon-decision-explained-more-money-pour-political-process
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McCutcheon_v._FEC

I think the FEC government website is almost definitely accurate with respect to current numbers, but no reference is given to past numbers on the site, which is what I am primarily trying to find at this point. I would also like to know the theoretical maximums of each type of limit.